# Remove Author Links

Tags: php, filters, jquery, author

I'm trying to remove the author pages as well as the links to the author pages on my wordpress website powered by Divi.

First, I disabled author archives and pages with the Yoast plugin.

Then, I used a short CSS snippet to disable the mouse pointer. It's working correctly, but the  balise was still existing. Meaning, the search engine bots were getting a 301 redirect when requesting the document.

So, I asked some guys on a Divi forum and they provided me the following snippet

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $(".author a").attr("href", "#");
    });
</script>
```

So, I added it. Nevertheless, there was still a  link looping on the same page. If I can see it in the source code, the googlebot can too.

[image: Here it is in the source code]

And I don't want it to waste its ressources on looping on the same page.

So, then I tried this snippet:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $(".author a").removeAttr("href");
    });
</script>
```

[image: What it looks in the source code]

While in the source code it seems "ok", when I crawl the website with Screaming Frog, it still finds many /author/ pages. But when I explore the source code of the "origin" pages, I don't find any link containing /author/ or the author name... (I flushed out the cache already)

I've been spending hours on this topic already. I'm open to any idea.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove in your  wordpress website powered by Divi.
then you can flow this some steps.
1.login your Dashboard.
2.Go to Appearance.
3.Then go to Theme Editor Or Editor.
4.There will a css code .
5.Paste this code

```
   .site-info { display: none; }
```